# Freezing windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, suspend

I am trying to freeze the form while `LoadNewQCDetails();` method is on process; but, even though the UI is disabled/suspend after completing the `LoadNewQCDetails();` method, all click events by the user will trigger. So,
I need to freeze the form such that the user can't click on anything in the UI till the `LoadNewQCDetails();` process completed.

**My code:**

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //this.SuspendLayout();
    //this.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;
    tabControl1.Enabled = false;
    groupBox1.Enabled = false;
    groupBox2.Enabled = false;
    groupBox3.Enabled = false;

    GlobalVariable.RefreshArtiCnt = 0;

    if (comboBox2.Text != "" )
    {
      //  LoadAllQCDetails();

        //this function takes nearly 1 minute to complete task
        LoadNewQCDetails();
    }
    else
    { MessageBox.Show("Data not found for this condition", "Alert"); }



    button3.Enabled = true;
    tabControl1.Enabled = true;
    groupBox1.Enabled = true;
    groupBox2.Enabled = true;
    groupBox3.Enabled = true;

    //this.Enabled = true;
    //   this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Comment: then do not show the form until the form has completely loading. you can add the long code into the `OnShowing` event and make the call to load whatever async if the data is large. Bam...! simple fix or if this method take a long time to complete `LoadNewQCDetails();` create a custom form with a timer on it , show that form modal using the ShowDialog() method, and alert the end users to be patient, that data is loading make take a few minutes.. what does the `LoadNewQCDetails();` method look like..? can that be loaded first async

Comment: is your LoadNewQCDetails contain large loop or query?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.hide()
 //shows the main page
  LoadNewQCDetails();
this.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all the controls in a panel and do panel.enabled=false; just before calling your method and panel.enabled=true; after method call.